# How to add Button on the Apple Pass Card

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, laravel-8, apple-wallet

I want to add a button on the passcard. I am using Laravel 8 to create a passcard. I can see that layout does not support doing so. Is there any way we can add a button on the passcard and that button will act as a clickable URL to route to some web link. Please help me to achieve this.

I am looking forward to hearing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot add button(s) on cards, maybe on **Passes** like boarding tickets, but the only link I can see on **Passes** is a image button (logo of the app) redirecting to the ios app linked.

#### Alternative for cards you can do:

1. Format your card with a text encouraging the user to press the dots button.
2. Then on card description you can add links

[image]

[image]